# Error when checking input: expected input_12 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (None, None, None, None, None)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to classify 24 RGB images belonging to 2 classes. Each image was originally of dimension 400 X 400, but has been resized to 32 X 32 in the code. Iam using the metric-learning for image similarity search algorithm. However, I obtain the error " Error when checking input.....", when I run the line **history = model.fit(AnchorPositivePairs(num_batchs=2), epochs=20)** at the end of the program. What could be causing this error?

Here is my code!

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from collections import defaultdict
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import utils
import glob
import os
import tqdm

IMG_DIR = "C:/Temp2/AGAIN_4/" # load the images from one directory
IM_WIDTH = 32
IM_HEIGHT = 32

#batch_size = 2
num_classes = 2
#epochs = 15

def read_images(directory, resize_to=(32, 32)): # extract image labels
    """
    Reads images and labels from the given directory
    :param directory directory from which to read the files
    :param resize_to a tuple of width, height to resize the images
    : returns a tuple of list of images and labels
    """
    files = glob.glob(directory + "*.jpg")
    images = []
    labels = []
    for f in tqdm.tqdm_notebook(files):
        im = Image.open(f)
        im = im.resize(resize_to)
        im = np.array(im) / 255.0
        im = im.astype("float32")
        images.append(im)
        label = 1 if 'microwave' in f.lower() else 0
        labels.append(label)
    return np.array(images), np.array(labels)
 
x, y = read_images(directory=IMG_DIR, resize_to=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT))
# make sure we have 25000 images if we are reading the full data set.
# Change the number accordingly if you have created a subset
assert len(x) == len(y) == 24 #25000

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  # extract train and test data
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25)
# remove X and y since we don't need them anymore
# otherwise it will just use the memory
del x
del y


x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')


# Display some of the images

height_width = 32


def show_collage(examples):
    box_size = height_width + 2
    num_rows, num_cols = examples.shape[:2]

    collage = Image.new(
        mode="RGB",
        size=(num_cols * box_size, num_rows * box_size),
        color=(250, 250, 250),
    )
    for row_idx in range(num_rows):
        for col_idx in range(num_cols):
            array = (np.array(examples[row_idx, col_idx]) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
            collage.paste(
                Image.fromarray(array), (col_idx * box_size, row_idx * box_size)
            )

    # Double size for visualisation.
    collage = collage.resize((2 * num_cols * box_size, 2 * num_rows * box_size))
    return collage


# Show a collage of 3x3 random images.

sample_idxs = np.random.randint(0, 15, size=(3, 3))
examples = x_train[sample_idxs]
show_collage(examples)  # Displays 9 images

class_idx_to_train_idxs = defaultdict(list)
for y_train_idx, y in enumerate(y_train):
    class_idx_to_train_idxs[y].append(y_train_idx)

class_idx_to_test_idxs = defaultdict(list)
for y_test_idx, y in enumerate(y_test):
    class_idx_to_test_idxs[y].append(y_test_idx)


num_classes = 2


class AnchorPositivePairs(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, num_batchs):
        self.num_batchs = num_batchs

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num_batchs

    def __getitem__(self, _idx):
        x = np.empty((2, num_classes, height_width, height_width, 3), dtype=np.float32)
        for class_idx in range(num_classes):
            examples_for_class = class_idx_to_train_idxs[class_idx]
            anchor_idx = random.choice(examples_for_class)
            positive_idx = random.choice(examples_for_class)
            while positive_idx == anchor_idx:
                positive_idx = random.choice(examples_for_class)
            x[0, class_idx] = x_train[anchor_idx]
            x[1, class_idx] = x_train[positive_idx]
        return x

examples = next(iter(AnchorPositivePairs(num_batchs=1)))

show_collage(examples)

class EmbeddingModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        # Note: Workaround for open issue, to be removed.
        if isinstance(data, tuple):
            data = data[0]
        anchors, positives = data[0], data[1]

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Run both anchors and positives through model.
            anchor_embeddings = self(anchors, training=True)
            positive_embeddings = self(positives, training=True)

            # Calculate cosine similarity between anchors and positives. As they have
            # been normalised this is just the pair wise dot products.
            similarities = tf.einsum(
                "ae,pe->ap", anchor_embeddings, positive_embeddings
            )

            # Since we intend to use these as logits we scale them by a temperature.
            # This value would normally be chosen as a hyper parameter.
            temperature = 0.2
            similarities /= temperature
            
             # We use these similarities as logits for a softmax. The labels for
            # this call are just the sequence [0, 1, 2, ..., num_classes] since we
            # want the main diagonal values, which correspond to the anchor/positive
            # pairs, to be high. This loss will move embeddings for the
            # anchor/positive pairs together and move all other pairs apart.
            sparse_labels = tf.range(num_classes)
            loss = self.compiled_loss(sparse_labels, similarities)

        # Calculate gradients and apply via optimizer.
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.trainable_variables))

        # Update and return metrics (specifically the one for the loss value).
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(sparse_labels, similarities)
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}

inputs = layers.Input(shape=(height_width, height_width, 3))
#inputs = layers.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation="relu")(inputs)
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
embeddings = layers.Dense(units=8, activation=None)(x)
embeddings = tf.nn.l2_normalize(embeddings, axis=-1)

model = EmbeddingModel(inputs, embeddings)

model.summary()

model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
)

history = model.fit(AnchorPositivePairs(num_batchs=2), epochs=20)

plt.plot(history.history["loss"])
plt.show()
```

I have used the cifar10 dataset as input instead of my local directory images as shown in the next code, but I still get the same error.

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from collections import defaultdict
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

"""
## Dataset
For this example we will be using the
[CIFAR-10](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) dataset.
"""

from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255.0
y_train = np.squeeze(y_train)
x_test = x_test.astype("float32") / 255.0
y_test = np.squeeze(y_test)

"""
To get a sense of the dataset we can visualise a grid of 25 random examples.
"""

height_width = 32


def show_collage(examples):
    box_size = height_width + 2
    num_rows, num_cols = examples.shape[:2]

    collage = Image.new(
        mode="RGB",
        size=(num_cols * box_size, num_rows * box_size),
        color=(250, 250, 250),
    )
    for row_idx in range(num_rows):
        for col_idx in range(num_cols):
            array = (np.array(examples[row_idx, col_idx]) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
            collage.paste(
                Image.fromarray(array), (col_idx * box_size, row_idx * box_size)
            )

    # Double size for visualisation.
    collage = collage.resize((2 * num_cols * box_size, 2 * num_rows * box_size))
    return collage


# Show a collage of 5x5 random images.
sample_idxs = np.random.randint(0, 50000, size=(5, 5))
examples = x_train[sample_idxs]
show_collage(examples)

"""
Metric learning provides training data not as explicit `(X, y)` pairs but instead uses
multiple instances that are related in the way we want to express similarity. In our
example we will use instances of the same class to represent similarity; a single
training instance will not be one image, but a pair of images of the same class. When
referring to the images in this pair we'll use the common metric learning names of the
`anchor` (a randomly chosen image) and the `positive` (another randomly chosen image of
the same class).
To facilitate this we need to build a form of lookup that maps from classes to the
instances of that class. When generating data for training we will sample from this
lookup.
"""

class_idx_to_train_idxs = defaultdict(list)
for y_train_idx, y in enumerate(y_train):
    class_idx_to_train_idxs[y].append(y_train_idx)

class_idx_to_test_idxs = defaultdict(list)
for y_test_idx, y in enumerate(y_test):
    class_idx_to_test_idxs[y].append(y_test_idx)

"""
For this example we are using the simplest approach to training; a batch will consist of
`(anchor, positive)` pairs spread across the classes. The goal of learning will be to
move the anchor and positive pairs closer together and further away from other instances
in the batch. In this case the batch size will be dictated by the number of classes; for
CIFAR-10 this is 10.
"""

num_classes = 10


class AnchorPositivePairs(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, num_batchs):
        self.num_batchs = num_batchs

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num_batchs

    def __getitem__(self, _idx):
        x = np.empty((2, num_classes, height_width, height_width, 3), dtype=np.float32)
        for class_idx in range(num_classes):
            examples_for_class = class_idx_to_train_idxs[class_idx]
            anchor_idx = random.choice(examples_for_class)
            positive_idx = random.choice(examples_for_class)
            while positive_idx == anchor_idx:
                positive_idx = random.choice(examples_for_class)
            x[0, class_idx] = x_train[anchor_idx]
            x[1, class_idx] = x_train[positive_idx]
        return x


"""
We can visualise a batch in another collage. The top row shows randomly chosen anchors
from the 10 classes, the bottom row shows the corresponding 10 positives.
"""

examples = next(iter(AnchorPositivePairs(num_batchs=1)))

show_collage(examples)

"""
## Embedding model
We define a custom model with a `train_step` that first embeds both anchors and positives
and then uses their pairwise dot products as logits for a softmax.
"""


class EmbeddingModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        # Note: Workaround for open issue, to be removed.
        if isinstance(data, tuple):
            data = data[0]
        anchors, positives = data[0], data[1]

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Run both anchors and positives through model.
            anchor_embeddings = self(anchors, training=True)
            positive_embeddings = self(positives, training=True)

            # Calculate cosine similarity between anchors and positives. As they have
            # been normalised this is just the pair wise dot products.
            similarities = tf.einsum(
                "ae,pe->ap", anchor_embeddings, positive_embeddings
            )

            # Since we intend to use these as logits we scale them by a temperature.
            # This value would normally be chosen as a hyper parameter.
            temperature = 0.2
            similarities /= temperature

            # We use these similarities as logits for a softmax. The labels for
            # this call are just the sequence [0, 1, 2, ..., num_classes] since we
            # want the main diagonal values, which correspond to the anchor/positive
            # pairs, to be high. This loss will move embeddings for the
            # anchor/positive pairs together and move all other pairs apart.
            sparse_labels = tf.range(num_classes)
            loss = self.compiled_loss(sparse_labels, similarities)

        # Calculate gradients and apply via optimizer.
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.trainable_variables))

        # Update and return metrics (specifically the one for the loss value).
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(sparse_labels, similarities)
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}


"""
Next we describe the architecture that maps from an image to an embedding. This model
simply consists of a sequence of 2d convolutions followed by global pooling with a final
linear projection to an embedding space. As is common in metric learning we normalise the
embeddings so that we can use simple dot products to measure similarity. For simplicity
this model is intentionally small.
"""

inputs = layers.Input(shape=(height_width, height_width, 3))
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation="relu")(inputs)
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
embeddings = layers.Dense(units=8, activation=None)(x)
embeddings = tf.nn.l2_normalize(embeddings, axis=-1)

model = EmbeddingModel(inputs, embeddings)

"""
Finally we run the training. On a Google Colab GPU instance this takes about a minute.
"""

model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
)

history = model.fit(AnchorPositivePairs(num_batchs=1000), epochs=20)

plt.plot(history.history["loss"])
plt.show()

"""
## Testing
We can review the quality of this model by applying it to the test set and considering
near neighbours in the embedding space.
First we embed the test set and calculate all near neighbours. Recall that since the
embeddings are unit length we can calculate cosine similarity via dot products.
"""

near_neighbours_per_example = 10

embeddings = model.predict(x_test)
gram_matrix = np.einsum("ae,be->ab", embeddings, embeddings)
near_neighbours = np.argsort(gram_matrix.T)[:, -(near_neighbours_per_example + 1) :]

"""
As a visual check of these embeddings we can build a collage of the near neighbours for 5
random examples. The first column of the image below is a randomly selected image, the
following 10 columns show the nearest neighbours in order of similarity.
"""

num_collage_examples = 5

examples = np.empty(
    (
        num_collage_examples,
        near_neighbours_per_example + 1,
        height_width,
        height_width,
        3,
    ),
    dtype=np.float32,
)
for row_idx in range(num_collage_examples):
    examples[row_idx, 0] = x_test[row_idx]
    anchor_near_neighbours = reversed(near_neighbours[row_idx][:-1])
    for col_idx, nn_idx in enumerate(anchor_near_neighbours):
        examples[row_idx, col_idx + 1] = x_test[nn_idx]

show_collage(examples)

"""
We can also get a quantified view of the performance by considering the correctness of
near neighbours in terms of a confusion matrix.
Let us sample 10 examples from each of the 10 classes and consider their near neighbours
as a form of prediction; that is, does the example and its near neighbours share the same
class?
We observe that each animal class does generally well, and is confused the most with the
other animal classes. The vehicle classes follow the same pattern.
"""

confusion_matrix = np.zeros((num_classes, num_classes))

# For each class.
for class_idx in range(num_classes):
    # Consider 10 examples.
    example_idxs = class_idx_to_test_idxs[class_idx][:10]
    for y_test_idx in example_idxs:
        # And count the classes of its near neighbours.
        for nn_idx in near_neighbours[y_test_idx][:-1]:
            nn_class_idx = y_test[nn_idx]
            confusion_matrix[class_idx, nn_class_idx] += 1

# Display a confusion matrix.
labels = [
    "Airplane",
    "Automobile",
    "Bird",
    "Cat",
    "Deer",
    "Dog",
    "Frog",
    "Horse",
    "Ship",
    "Truck",
]
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=confusion_matrix, display_labels=labels)
disp.plot(include_values=True, cmap="viridis", ax=None, xticks_rotation="vertical")
plt.show()


ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_16 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (None, None, None, None, None)
```

Comment: @claymorehack. I am not sure where I should place this code you have just given me.

Comment: @Mr. T & @ claymorehack. This code runs well on the free GPU google colab server. But, I am running it on CPU, could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure but as i understand it your own data generator cause this error. You should also pass to try your data size in generator, try this:

```
def __len__(self):
    if self.batch_size > self.X.shape[0]:
        print("Batch size is greater than data size!!")
        return -1
    return int(np.floor(self.X.shape[0] / self.batch_size))
```